# Error running library(httr) in R studio Version 0.99.489 on windows 7 64

Tags: r, path, corrupt, httr

I installed `httr` and it was working.
I then ran `install.packages("devtools")` and `devtools::install_github("hadley/httr")` and selected allow path re-write.

I now get the following error when running `library(httr)`:

> Error in `get(Info[i, 1], envir = env)` :    lazy-load database
>   `'C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/httr/R/httr.rdb'` is corrupt

In addition:

> Warning message: In `get(Info[i, 1], envir = env)` :
>   internal error -3 in `R_decompress1`
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for `‘httr’`

I have removed manually the `httr` package and re-installed but keep hitting the same error.

My first guess is that the path environment variable is wrong as googling showed someone have a similar issue with an `rJava` install where the `Java_Home` path had to be reset.

My current path is:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\Rtools\bin;C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\php\php;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\
```

I think the `Rtools` part may also be incorrect. 
`library(Rtools)` yields

> Error in `library(Rtools)` : there is no package called `‘Rtools’`.

The package is located here:
`C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\3.2\Rtools`

Any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Thank you,

Q

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your issue, but on some occasions you get an error (this error, I can't recall for sure, but possibly) when trying to load a library you've just installed and you haven't restarted your R session.

After your package install (assuming no error message from the install), try quitting R, restarting, and then seeing if you can load your library with library(...)